# inserting fields with the same name through ajax / jquery into database

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a form on my website that allows users to enter names and email addresses for guests that they are inviting to an event. So there is 3 fields per line

name, email, phone number

the user can click a button and it clones the fields allowing users to input as many guests as they want.

I've got it passing the input through ajax. However I am wondering how can I insert into my database as a row per guests info?

```
foreach ($this->input->post('paidforguestemail')):

$insert['name'] = $this->input->post('paidforguestname');
$insert['email'] = $this->input->post('paidforguestemail');
$insert['phone'] = $this->input->post('paidforguestphone');
$this->db->insert("bookings", $insertbookings);  

endforeach;
```

each field is named like 'paidforguestname[]'

How can i insert the right phone number and email and name from each row?

i.e -

`Name : John` `Email : john@john.com` `Phone : 0785088888`
`Name : Jamie` `Email : jamie@jamie.com` `Phone : 07825088888`

I am using the following to post the data through AJAX

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://XXXXX.com/events/finishevent",
  method: "POST",
  data: $("#formcomplete").serialize(),
  success: function (msg) {
});
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL here, neither in question, nor in answers.)

Answer (score 0):

How about you create one bit of JSON from your fields, and just POST that one JSON string?

Then in PHP, you have an array with your rows, after `json_decode()`ing.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Delboy",
    "email": "delboy@work.com",
    "phone": "0012345678",
  },
  {
    "name": "Jack",
    "email": "jack@work.com",
    "name": "0012345678",
  }
]
```

Comment: Issue is, there are many more fields in the form that are to do with the actual booking, this is just one more section that allows users to add guests that they're paying for,

Comment: Ok. Make the guest fields NOT part of your form. Get the form as a JSON object, Create and add the guest JSON to it under key `paidforguestnames`, then serialise and send that.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($this->input->post('paidforguestemail'));

    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

    $insert['name'] = $this->input->post('paidforguestemail')[$i];
    $insert['email'] = $this->input->post('paidforguestemail')[$i];
    $insert['phone'] = $this->input->post('paidforguestphone')[$i];

    $this->db->insert("bookings", $insertbookings);  
    }
```